# How can I implement a GraphQL API in Laravel while still utilizing Eloquent models and relationships?

Tags: php, laravel, graphql

I'm currently working on a Laravel application, and it needs a powerful API in order for the front-end application to function properly. I've come to the conclusion that GraphQL is the best choice for my API; however, I'm having trouble determining the most effective way to connect it with the Eloquent models and relationships that I already have.

To be more specific, I want to be able to query related models using GraphQL syntax (for example, "user { posts { title } }"), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to translate that syntax to the underlying Eloquent queries in the database.

I have investigated the possibility of using a package for Laravel such as Lighthouse or GraphQL, but I am unsure how to modify the schema in order to accommodate my particular use case.

Does anyone know of anyone who has successfully implemented a GraphQL API in Laravel while still making use of Eloquent models and relationships? If that's the case, would you be able to give me some pointers on how to get started, as well as some warnings about potential pitfalls?

Comment: There may be GraphQL libraries with Laravel support. Quick google search reveals [this one](https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel) for example.